# Prove the product topology of $X\times Y$ is indeed a topology by using axioms ONLY and NOT using the knowledge of basis

Tags: general-topology, alternative-proof

In many topology books, the product topology of $X\times Y$ is defined via a basis, that is a topology generated by the basis $$\mathcal{B}:=\{U\times V:U\ \text{open in}\ X, V\ \text{open in}\ Y\}.$$

However, what if we assume NO knowledge of basis, but define a collection of sets $\mathcal{T}$ consisting of unions of sets of the form $U\times V$, where $U$ open in $X$ and $V$ open in $Y$?

Then, to show $\mathcal{T}$ is indeed a topology, the only thing we can use are those three axioms of being a topology. Then, how can I show $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology?

Then it is by definition that $\bigcup_{i\in I}(U\times V)_{i}\in \mathcal{T}$, since $\mathcal{T}$ contains any unions of sets of this form.

But how to show $X\times Y$, $\varnothing$ are open? and how to show $\mathcal{T}$ is closed under finite intersection?

It seems that we need to express everything into the form of the union of sets of the the product of open sets..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $X\times Y$ is open because both $X$ and $Y$ are open.

The empty set is open because it is equal to $\emptyset\times\emptyset$.

Finally, if $U_1$ and $U_2$ are open subset of $X$ and $V_1$ and $V_2$ are open subset of $Y$, then$$(U_1\times V_1)\cap(U_2\times V_2)=(U_1\cap U_2)\times(V_1\cap V_2).$$Now, if $A,B\in\mathcal T$, then$$A=\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda_1}U_\lambda\times V_\lambda\text{ and  }B=\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda_2}U_\lambda\times V_\lambda.$$And then you use the fact that$$A\cap B=\bigcup_{(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)\in\Lambda_1\times\Lambda_2}(U_{\lambda_1}\times V_{\lambda_1})\cap(U_{\lambda_2}\times V_{\lambda_2}).$$

Comment: but in the definition of $\mathcal{T}$ in this post, it is a collection of all unions of element in the basis, so I think we need to express $X\times Y$ as a unions of sets of the form $U\times V$. Same logic can also be applied to the intersection and empty set..

Comment: I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is clear now.

Comment: ah! that makes great sense.. but how could I show $X\times Y$ and $\varnothing$ are open? how could I express them as union of open sets?

Comment: I tried to use covering, i.e. $X\times Y\subset\bigcup_{\alpha}U_{\alpha}\times\bigcup_{\beta}V_{\beta}$, but since the indexes are not the same, I cannot pull the union out...

Comment: @JacobsonRadical what do you mean? $\cup_{\alpha,\beta}(U_\alpha\times V_\beta)$

Comment: Since $X$ is an open subset of $X$ and $Y$ is an open subset of $Y$, $X\times Y\in\mathcal T$. A similar argument applies to $\emptyset$ (since it is equal to $\emptyset\times\emptyset$).

Comment: @JacobsonRadical they're a union of **one** basic open set. Perfectly valid.

Comment: @Mirko oh! I don't know I can do that.. thank you!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Ah.. I didn't see I can do the union of one set. Now it's clear, thank you!

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Ah.. I didn't see I can do the union of one set. Thank you!